# 3d editor with quads polygons. Assimp

Tags: opengl, shader, polygon, assimp

Now I work on .obj loader for my 3d editor and plan to build it on Assimp. In my editor meshes will have a quad wireframe above triangulated polygons and have possibility to take both triangles forming a poltgon. But I know Assimp rebuild data for Opengl-ready and don't let to use quads. In my plan to stay data as .obj (quads) and do not triangulate it. If I remove `aiProcess_Triangulate` my render will corrupt and it doesn't render correctly. Which is a best way to stay data as quads without duplicate data with possibility to interact with it, and to prepare it for rendering? Can Assimp provide this option? Maybe only one way is to make loader myself?

Answer (score 0):

depends of what you mean by load. GL_QUADS removed in 3.1+ and renderer wouldn't recognise it,but for scene  building it's still useful.I can say that only trouble with own obj loader i'd have for now is sscanf and float,coz sscanf wanna no dot but comma  delimeter. https://rocketgit.com/user/bowler17/gl/source/tree/branch/wrench